# VB - How to sort a list of numbers into descending order

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm making a frequency analysis tool for text using Visual Basic. The code below takes in an input from the user and then tells them how many of each letter appears in the text they inputted and that works fine. However, I'm struggling to order the letters into descending order.

```
    Dim words, output
    Dim count = 0
    Dim letters As Array = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"}
    words = UCase(textInputBox.Text)
    For Each x In letters
        For Each i In words
            If x = i Then
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        If count <> 0 Then
            output = output & (x & " = " & count) & vbCrLf
            textOutputBox.Text = output
            letterReplaceBox.Text = words
        End If
        count = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

For example, the input of the text:
HELLO
would output:
E = 1

H = 1

L = 2

O = 1

Is there anyway I can then order these into descending order? I'm thinking of trying a two dimensional array with the letters and the numbers and then ordering from there? Or adding the numbers all to a list? Or using something like bubble sort? Or is there a more efficient way to do it? I'm not sure how to approach it...

Thank you for any suggestions or help (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable with LINQ. This will group your input by letter. There is some customization here. First the code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    Dim result =
        input.
        ToUpper().
        GroupBy(Function(c) c).
        OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count).
        Where(Function(g) Asc(g.First) >= 65 And Asc(g.First) <= 90).
        Select(Function(g) String.Format("'{0}' = {1}", g.First, g.Count))
    For Each r In result
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    Next
End Sub
```

This part of the code converts the input into uppercase (of course you could leave this out, but see the condition below which filters the letters).

```
ToUpper()
```

This is what groups by letter

```
GroupBy(Function(c) c)
```

This orders it by the number of elements

```
OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count)
```

This filters out anything but upper case letters (no spaces, punctuation, etc., see http://www.asciitable.com/)

```
Where(Function(g) Asc(g.First) >= 65 And Asc(g.First) <= 90)
```

This returns a formatted string with the letter and number of occurences.

```
Select(Function(g) String.Format("'{0}' = {1}", g.First, g.Count))
```

Of course, you could return anything you want but I did this for the demo.

This is the output of the code:

> 'O' = 4
>   
> 'E' = 3
>   
> 'T' = 2
>   
> 'H' = 2
>   
> 'U' = 2
>   
> 'R' = 2
>   
> 'Q' = 1
>   
> 'I' = 1
>   
> 'C' = 1
>   
> 'K' = 1
>   
> 'B' = 1
>   
> 'W' = 1
>   
> 'N' = 1
>   
> 'F' = 1
>   
> 'X' = 1
>   
> 'J' = 1
>   
> 'M' = 1
>   
> 'P' = 1
>   
> 'S' = 1
>   
> 'V' = 1
>   
> 'L' = 1
>   
> 'A' = 1
>   
> 'Z' = 1
>   
> 'Y' = 1
>   
> 'D' = 1
>   
> 'G' = 1

Comment: Good solution, but introducing Linq **is not the problem here**. I don't see anywhere you explain the OP issue and why it's not working. If you did, this would help the OP understand where they went wrong and why. Also this can be done without Linq as well.

Comment: From OP *I'm not sure how to approach it...*, hence a whole new approach. I tried to explain it as much as I could because it's an entirely different solution.

Comment: @Verdolino Hiya! Thank you so so much for your response and you explained everything so well, aaah it's so so helpful and easy to understand now. I can't thank you enough (:

Answer (score 1):

Another example to play with:

```
    Dim frequencies As New Dictionary(Of String, Tuple(Of String, Integer))
    For Each letter As String In textInputBox.Text.ToUpper.ToArray
        If Not frequencies.ContainsKey(letter) Then
            frequencies.Add(letter, New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(letter, 1))
        Else
            frequencies(letter) = New Tuple(Of String, Integer)(letter, frequencies(letter).Item2 + 1)
        End If
    Next

    Dim results = frequencies.Values.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Item2).ToList
    Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each pair In results
        output.AppendLine(pair.Item1 & " = " & pair.Item2)
    Next
    textOutputBox.Text = output.ToString
```

Comment: Looks fine, I'll counter that

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you so so much for this code as well, my teacher at school suggested using a dictionary like you did and now I can see how it all works. Thank you (:

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sorry to be a pain, but quick question, could you explain to me what the first IF selection does in your code please? I hope it's not too much trouble, thank you!

Comment: The first IF creates and adds an initial Tuple with a count of 1 to the Dictionary when the Letter is not yet present as a Key.  The ELSE portion increments the count if the Key is already present.

Comment: A Custom Class could be used instead of the somewhat awkward Tuple, but not sure if you've progressed that far in your studies.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Ah okay thank you very much that makes sense now (: And I haven't used or heard of a Custom Class before, so I'm going to stick with the Tuple. Thanks again!